# Algorithms that solve a practical problem but have not been proven correct

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

Are there any known famous and usable algorithms that seem to solve some famous problem but which haven't been proven to be correct?

Comment: In view of [proofs and programs being the same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), I think what you ask for amounts to [famous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_conjectures) [conjectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjecture).

Comment: There are various primality checking algorithms that rely  on various conjectures, such as the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: Philosophically, every normal human mind is probably an algorithm that solves lots of practical famous problems (such as image recognition) but have not been proven correct. More compute-science-ly, many approximation algorithms such as some of the recent Artificial Intelligence have not been proven correct (they might have been proven to be correct within some factors, though).